# adb not prompting on android for permission

Tags: android, adb

Im trying to setup my android device for debugging. I have adb debuging enabled in the developer settings. I list adb devices and it shows the device as 'no permissions'.
The popup prompt that should display on the android device has not shown up. Is there a way to force this popup open so I can give permission to allow adb?

Comment: Try switching the USB cable.  You'd be surprised how often it's the cable...  Failing that, reboot both devices.

Comment: You can try to turn 'usb debugging' option off and then on again. It might also help.